# apply function that takes row as an argument to each row in data.table

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data.table
`dt = structure(list(x = 1:3, y = 3:5), .Names = c("x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))`

Also, I have a given function that takes a row and dataset as an argument. For example, lets

```
function_sum <- function(i, dataset){
  x <- as.numeric(dataset[i,1])
  y <- as.numeric(dataset[i,2])
  x+y
}
```

I need to apply this function to each row in my dataset and have no idea how to do it.

It doesn't work
`dt[, function_sum(i=.SDrow, dataset=dt), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]`

Comment: why is the function not vectorized? Can't you write a vectorized function and subset outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Using your `function_sum()` function:

```r
sapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) function_sum(i,dt))
#[1] 4 6 8
```